# Serializing DateTime to time without milliseconds and gmt

Tags: .net, time, xml-serialization, attributes

I have created a C# class file by using a XSD-file as an input. One of my properties look like this:

```
 private System.DateTime timeField;

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="time")]
 public System.DateTime Time {
     get {
         return this.timeField;
     }
     set {
         this.timeField = value;
     }
 }
```

When serialized, the contents of the file now looks like this:

```
<Time>14:04:02.1661975+02:00</Time>
```

Is it possible, with XmlAttributes on the property, to have it render without the milliseconds and the GMT-value like this?

```
<Time>14:04:02</Time>
```

Is this possible, or do i need to hack together some sort of xsl/xpath-replace-magic after the class has been serialized?

It is not a solution to changing the object to String, because it is used like a DateTime in the rest of the application and allows us to create an xml-representation from an object by using the XmlSerializer.Serialize() method.

The reason I need to remove the extra info from the field is that the receiving system does not conform to the w3c-standards for the time datatype.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534525/force-xmlserializer-to-serialize-datetime-as-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create a string property that does the translation to/from your timeField field and put the serialization attribute on that instead the the real DateTime property that the rest of the application uses.

Comment: I had to do exactly the same today  :)

Comment: Will this also work if we later need to deserialize the same file?

Comment: That is how i solved it. Which I could accept both answers, but Jeffrey was first. The best I can do is an upvote :)

Comment: if your XSD isn't going to change, I think this is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 24):

Put [XmlIgnore] on the Time property.

Then add a new property:

```
[XmlElement(DataType="string",ElementName="Time")]
public String TimeString
{
    get { return this.timeField.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
    set { this.timeField = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
}
```

Comment: Is `"yyyy-MM-dd"` the correct format string for a time field? While this solution didn't work for me out of the box, it did lead me to one that did.  I had to use `"HH:mm:ss"`, and I sourced from my `dateField` like this `get { return this.dateField.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); }`

Comment: Same goes for Uri data type as well.  That was my problem, and this is how I fixed it.

    [JsonIgnore]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Uri UrlIgnore { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    [XmlElement]
    public string Url
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(UrlIgnore); }
        set { UrlIgnore = new Uri(value); }
    }