# Does UTC observe daylight saving time?

Tags: php, time, dst

I am trying to write a script where i want to convert any timezone to `UTC` and reverse.
But  from some where i came to know that while converting any timezone to `UTC`  with or without DST consideration it will give the same `UTC` time.
For example:
If i try to convert this one:

```
$mytime = '2011-03-31 05:06:00.000';
$myzone = 'America/New_York';
```

to UTC with DST and without DST,i will get ..

```
(New_York->UTC DST=Yes)2011-03-31 09:06:00
(New_York->UTC DST=No)2011-03-31 09:06:00 ..........
```

Is this corect ??If yes then why???
Please anybody give me your answers.

Comment: If you show us the script, we can help you a bit better.

Comment: And, in answer to your title question, no UTC does not observe daylight savings; other zones, however, may.

Answer (score 159):

No, UTC itself never has DST. It is the constant frame of reference other time zones are expressed relative to.

From the [Wikipedia UTC page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> UTC does not change with a change of seasons, but local time or civil time may change if a time zone jurisdiction observes daylight saving time or summer time. For example, UTC is 5 hours ahead of local time on the east coast of the United States during winter, but 4 hours ahead during summer.

In other words, when a time zone observes DST, its offset from UTC changes when there's a DST transition, but that's *that time zone* observing DST, not UTC.

Without knowing much about PHP time zone handling, it seems strange to me that you can specify "with DST" or "without DST" in a conversion - the time zones themselves specify when DST kicks in... it shouldn't have to be something you specify yourself.

Comment: "Without knowing much about PHP time zone handling, it seems strange to me that you can specify 'with DST' or 'without DST' in a conversion"...that's probably because you haven't done much Programmable Hyperlinked Pasta. This is the language with a builtin `date_sunrise` function to tell you when the sun rises. I'm not sure if DST is needed for conversion, but it is a first-class citizen of a date object: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Being a first-class citizen of the date object makes a certain amount of sense - just not specifying it separately for the conversion. I've since learned a bit more about some of the underlying C routines, however, and I suspect they have a lot to do with this...

Comment: I think it's okay to ask if it is DST. One cannot move from a localtime+timezone to an unambiguous UTC time without that extra info. This is because some localtimes occur twice during the transition out of DST.

Comment: @Tom: I'm very well aware of local times occurring twice, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to specify whether or not a local time is in DST in the conversion itself. It's better - IMO - to specify a way of resolving the ambiguity *if* it's ambiguous. I prefer APIs to avoid allowing you to express impossible situations, such as EDT in January.

Comment: So you want a rule which instructs *how* to resolve it when ambiguous? What is a sensible rule? I've only seen APIs that require a declaration, rather than a rule. Examples: moment.js, pytz's localize. (In pytz, you cannot, AFAIK, create EDT in January since you specify IANA timezones, but you still have to use is_dst while localizing.)

Comment: @Tom: See my Noda Time API for an example :) The "right thing to do" really depends on the app.

Comment: If you're confused about how to do timezone in PHP, it's because PHP is a mess, here's a fantastic writeup of why php should just be retired:  https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue, using this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$nowdate = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
echo "Current date and time is: " . $nowdate;
```

It is summer now, and the time this code produces is one hour behind - so I don't think that UTC time in PHP adjusts to DST.

Be interesting to see if anyone has the solution...

EDIT:

Found this code on a forum, works perfectly!!

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$TIME =  date("m/d/Y H:i",time());
```

So you can then call the current date and time by using $TIME.
The output can be adjusted to display it differently by changing the bit inside the date() tag.
If you want to adjust the date() output, use this guide: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well, that is correct then, as when you set timezone to UTC, during summer you would get a time that is one hour behind your local time (in London). https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london