# How do you create numpy.datetime64 object from a unix timestamp and set the timezone to UTC?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a process where I read in a bunch of strings in ISO 8601 format at Zulu or UTC time. For example,

```
2012-06-20T21:15:00Z
2012-06-20T21:16:00Z
2012-06-20T21:17:00Z
2012-06-20T21:18:00Z
```

I convert the strings into timezone aware python datetime objects and then save them in a binary format as integers by converting them to Unix Timestamps. For example,

```
dt_str = '2012-06-20T21:15:00Z'
ts = int(mktime(datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').timetuple()))
# ts = 1340241300
```

When I read these timestamps back into another process I would like to instantiate a numpy.datetime64 object directly from the timestamp. The problem is that datetime64 sets the timezone to my local timezone.

```
np_dt = np.datetime64(ts,'s')
# np_dt = numpy.datetime64('2012-06-20T21:15:00-0400')
```

Does anyone know of a way that I could read in my timestamp so that it is UTC time? Would I would like for np_dt to equal is numpy.datetime64('2012-06-20T21:15:00-0000')...I think.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module to help out. First, create a datetime object from the timestamp integer you saved:

```
>>> ts = 1340241300
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 20, 21, 15, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Then pass it to numpy, which will convert it to the local timezone (I am in -4):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.datetime64(dt.isoformat())
numpy.datetime64('2012-06-20T17:15:00-0400')
```

Comment: So the idea is to convert the UTC to local timezone so that when numpy attaches the local timezone it will at least reflect the correct time? I wonder how well that works with daylight savings transitions.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It should work fine regardless of the local timezone

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like I may be better off just leaving the timestamp as a string. I'll have to do some more reading on datetime64, but ideally I would always like to work with UTC time.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the datetim64 to show as UTC. The time above **is** the same as your UTC time, but in the local timezone.

Comment: Ah yes, understood. It seems as though the best way to go may be to leave the timestamps as strings.

Answer (score 4):

What about setting the timezone for your code.

```
import os, time
os.environ['TZ'] = 'GMT'
time.tzset()
# then your code 
np_dt = np.datetime64(ts,'s')
```

Comment: Looks like this requires numpy >= 1.7.0.  Creation of datetime64 does not appear to allow for specifying seconds in 1.6.2:

    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.get_distribution('numpy').version
    '1.6.2'

    np.datetime64(1338624706, 's')
    TypeError: function takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Code seems wrong to me: Is utc and gmt the same? (what about day-light savings, utc does NOT follow day-light savings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495803/does-utc-observe-daylight-saving-time....)

Comment: UTC is more recent and more precise than GMT. It's better to use UTC. They both do not follow Daylight savings. http://geography.about.com/od/timeandtimezones/a/gmtutc.htm

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html), the only way to do it is to create it from a string that specifies the time zone directly. Thus you'll need to create a `datetime.datetime` object first and format it to a string with `'Z'` appended, then construct the `numpy.datetime64` from that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to determine what I gain from storing the timestamp as an integer vs what it cost to convert it back to a string append the 'Z' and then instantiate a datetime64 object.