# UTC time differences between two servers with different TZ

Tags: java, date, utc

My server is located in country **A** and I am getting a **UTC** timestamp from server in country **B**. I also receive the timezone offset and daylight savings from that server.

What I need to do is calculate the difference (in seconds) between server **A** local time and the received timestamp from server **B**.

My current solution is (implemented on server **A**) :

```
long localUTCTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
long timeDiff = localUTCTime - serverBUTCTime;
```

My question is should I take daylight savings in account here ? or is this solution should work regardless.

**EDIT:**

The time from server B is a timestamp of an event the happened some time ago

Comment: First you need to check where the server B time is including day-light saving ? If no, you should take into account

Comment: If you have UTC time stamps from both servers, the difference should be sufficient.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen so the solution above should give me the correct difference ? I have no control on server B I just know that it sends its local time in UTC

Comment: @Ved Why? UTC has a precise definition - in particular there is not time change due to day light saving, ever.

Comment: @giorashc see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5495816/829571

Comment: UTC is UTC, minor discrepancies in the server clocks aside, `localUTCTime - serverBUTCTime` would equal zero.  The U stands for Universal

Comment: @NickHolt you a right, I should have specified the the time from server B is of an event that happened some time ago (usually a few seconds)

Comment: @giorashc in that case, the difference between an event that occurred a 10:00 UTC and a current time of 10:01 UTC is simply the later subtracted from the former or 1 minute.  There's no daylight saving to worry about

Comment: UTC is a global time.  Local time is UTC interpreted with regard to timezone and daylight savings time etc.

Comment: You should, however, be certain that both servers synchronize against timeservers (typically with NTP), so their clocks are accurate.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have no control nor access to that information on server B. I'll have to check it once we start testing the whole thing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Ok, then as I understand the solution I provided should work and give me the correct difference (in case server B is indeed synchronized as mentioned by ThorbjørnRavnAndersen). I'll keep the TZ and DST on a shelf for now;). Thank you all for your help!