# Joda LocalDate To LocalDateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to convert `Joda LocalDate` to `Joda LocalDateTime`, for that I am using the method `toLocalDateTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)`, as of now it is working
fine for example: for the given joda Localdate `2025-02-28` I getting the expected joda LocalDateTime `2025-02-28T00:00:00.000`, But my fear is, whether this method works fine at all situation. For example `during dayLight saving` `time zone anomalies`..etc..

**Update:** I did a small research on this question, here it is

`toLocalDateTime(LocalTime time)` [Documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toLocalDateTime(org.joda.time.LocalTime)) saying that: Converts LocalDate object to a LocalDateTime with `LocalTime` to fill in the missing fields.

As I initializing `LocalTime` with `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT`, from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/1.5.2/org/joda/time/LocalTime.java#LocalTime%60%20I%20came%20to%20know%20%60LocalTime.MIDNIGHT) `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` is a static final field initialized to `new LocalTime(0, 0, 0, 0);`, you can see that it is a time values are hardcode to zero values with `ISOChronology getInstanceUTC()`, so I think I will get the required output without any issue.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether there's likely to be a bug in the Joda library.  I guess anything is possible, but I'd say it's probably been tested much better than anything you're likely to write for yourself.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).  `java.time.LocalDate.parse( "2025-02-28" ).atStartOfDay()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/), we know that

> - LocalDate is an immutable datetime class representing **a date without a time zone**.
> - LocalDateTime is an unmodifiable datetime class representing a **datetime without a time zone**.
> - Internally, LocalDateTime uses a **single millisecond-based value** to represent the local datetime. This value is only used internally and is not exposed to applications.
> - Calculations on LocalDate are performed using a Chronology. This chronology will be set internally to be **in the UTC time zone for all calculations**.

We also know that the `toLocalDateTime` method of `LocalDate` class is implemented like [this](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/LocalDate.java):

```
public LocalDateTime toLocalDateTime(LocalTime time) {
   if (time == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The time must not be null");
   }
   if (getChronology() != time.getChronology()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The chronology of the time does not match");
   }
   long localMillis = getLocalMillis() + time.getLocalMillis();
   return new LocalDateTime(localMillis, getChronology());
}
```

Considering also that [UTC has no Daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495803/does-utc-observe-daylight-saving-time), we can conclude that you don't have to fear daylight saving problems nor time zone anomalies using the `toLocalDateTime` method because this method dont deal with timezones.