# PHP daylight saving always false

Tags: php, date, timezone

I would like to know whether a date is in daylight saving time.

So I do this:

```
echo date('I', strtotime('2017-03-23')); // outputs 0
echo date('I', strtotime('2017-03-29')); // outputs 0
```

I expect to have different results for the two inputs, as the switch in the UK is 26 March 2017, however the output is 0 in both cases.

I have checked and the time zone looks correct:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get(); // outputs UTC
```

Comment: Check with `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London")`, [it works on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JL2lL)

Comment: I'm guessing being the timezone is UTC you don't have daylight savings time.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495803/does-utc-observe-daylight-saving-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495816), `UTC` does not have daylight saving, you need to set your timezone to `Europe/London` :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); 
echo date('I', strtotime('2017-03-23')); // echoes 0
echo date('I', strtotime('2017-03-29')); // echoes 1

date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
echo date('I', strtotime('2017-03-23')); // echoes 0
echo date('I', strtotime('2017-03-29')); // echoes 0
```