# Why is there an extra 1/4 of a day in this time calculation?

Tags: javascript, date

I was trying to do a basic date calculation as seen below. I want to find the remaining days in the month given the arguments below.

I thought I determined a solution, but there appears to be an extra 1/4 in the answer.

```js
// returns last day of month
function lastDayOfMonth(date) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)
}

let day_start = new Date('2018-11-04');
let day_end = new Date('2019-01-10');
let day_last = lastDayOfMonth(day_start);


let total = 0;
if (day_end <= day_last) {
  total = day_end - day_start;
} else {
  total = day_last - day_start;
}
console.log(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // returns 26.25
```

Comment: Your date range includes the day that daylight saving time changes, so there's an extra hour.

Comment: I get `26.208333333333332` (I'm in Eastern time in the US).

Comment: calculations appear to be using unix epoch time, that is msec since 1970 and not be consistent ... according to @heretic

Comment: Ah javascript dates. When I heard quarter of a day, I immediately thought of leap year. Each calendar year is actually a quarter day short of an orbital year, so leap year adds a day to make up for it.

Comment: `Date` objects are stored as exactly that: milliseconds since the epoch in UTC (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) they are stored that way consistently though.

Comment: Try logging `day_start`, `day_end`, and `day_last` and I think you'll see the problem. `day_last` is the beginning of the day UTC, the others are in the local timezone.

Comment: @JasonWilliams Except it's not a quarter of a day for people in the Eastern timezone. For me it's `.2083333`

Comment: For me it's exactly 26. But I'm in GMT+0

Comment: related ... syntax ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: So the problem is that you're adding in your timezone offset. The extra .25 is because you're 6 hours behind UTC.

Comment: @phuzi - that is what I said. 6 hours, the UTC offset of my location.

Comment: @Barmar - throwing darts works some times!

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the UTC offset, since as you have it written, `day_start` and `day_end` are midnight UTC, but `day_last` is midnight in your local timezone.

To fix, just do all calculations in UTC. Since `day_last` is the only one that is local, this is the only one you need to adjust. In order to produce this in UTC, you could use the `setUTCFullYear` and related methods (sadly I don't believe there is a way to do it with the `Date` constructor):

```js
// returns last day of month
function lastDayOfMonth(date) {
  // Set correct date in UTC:
  let last_date = new Date();
  last_date.setUTCFullYear(date.getFullYear());
  last_date.setUTCMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  last_date.setUTCDate(0);

  // Zero out the time so that this will end up as midnight:
  last_date.setUTCHours(0);
  last_date.setUTCMinutes(0);
  last_date.setUTCSeconds(0);
  last_date.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
  return last_date;
}

let day_start = new Date('2018-11-04');
let day_end = new Date('2019-01-10');
let day_last = lastDayOfMonth(day_start);


let total = 0;
if (day_end <= day_last) {
  total = day_end - day_start;
} else {
  total = day_last - day_start;
}
console.log(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // returns 26 flat
```

Comment: maybe simpler to just put the offset in for the 3rd function.  Is there a method to retrieve UTC offset?

Comment: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` will return the offset in _minutes_, however keep in mind that the offset changes depending on which `date` is used, because of DST.

Comment: let offset = ( date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60 );  should be more concise.

Comment: DST only matters if you are not careful. If you want to add the offset inside `lastDayOfMonth`, you must ensure you use the offset of the constructed date, _not_ the offset of the `date` argument, as it could be one hour off due to DST change between the two times. Personally I don't like reasoning about DST as it often get it wrong. Hence my instinct is always to do everything in UTC, but YMMV.

Comment: DST should not effect UTC in any way according to ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495803/does-utc-observe-daylight-saving-time

Comment: Yes, if you do everything in UTC, then DST does not matter. However using the offset to convert from local time to UTC may involve DST error when done naively, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243397/discussion-between-crice-and-jon-jon-bon-bon).

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` constructor using the format, `new Date(year, month, day)` is evaluated using your local time zone.  The `Date` constructor for the ISO 8601 string, `YYYY-MM-DD` is evaluated in UTC.

You can resolve this by printing your local date in ISO 8601 format and passing that into a newly constructed Date object.

```
function lastDayOfMonth(date) {
  let localDate=new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0);
  let m=localDate.getMonth();
  let d=localDate.getDate();
  return new Date(localDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(m<10?'0':'')+m+'-'+ (d<10?'0':'')+d);
}
```