# Parsing Date Time String returns Incorrectly

Tags: c#, xml, datetime

I have an azure web service that delivers XML files to a number of customers.

The user will send an XML file to the web service and it will de-serialize the XML to an Object and then serialize it to the XML format required by the customer.

I have come across an odd situation, where there are two different DateTime formats in the XML file being sent to the web service, in this case the DateTimes in the XML file which has been outputted are incorrect. However if I feed the two DateTimes in two separate files both are Parsed correctly.

Here are the two DateTimes:

> Date="2015-09-23T14:30:00+01:00"
>
> Date="2015-09-23T14:30:00"

When parsed in a file with one or the other they both parse as 14:30 which is correct, however when both formats are in the file the second DateTime parses as 15:30 and the first 14:30.

I have tried assigning CultureInfo, setting to local time.

I am using the [XmlSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the XML file sent to the web service to the object I have created.

I then have a simple mapper which writes the values to the XML and changes a few attribute and node names. The code to write the DateTime to string is:

```
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("startdatetime", dateTime.ToString("s"))
```

What is really throwing me is that this all works when they are in separate files but not when it is in a file with two separate DateTime formats.

Comment: Surely you should be using a common UTC time format across your solution?

Comment: Yes I should, but my manager won't give the go ahead for this to be done at the present time.

Comment: What happens when you change your properties from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: If you parse it as a `DateTimeOffset`, then serialize it like this: `dto.DateTime.ToString("s")` - you should be get the correct result.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It is expected that all of the times are 14:30

Comment: @Rob I'm not actually doing a parse of the XML it is all being handled by the XmlSerializer

Comment: @BenSharpe Right - but I mean, change your class that you're deserializing into to use `DateTimeOffset` properties instead of `DateTime`. So instead of `public DateTime startTime {get;set;}` you have `public DateTimeOffset startTime {get;set;}`. Then replace `xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("startdatetime", dateTime.ToString("s"))` with `xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("startdatetime", dateTime.DateTime.ToString("s"))`

Comment: @BenSharpe So the two outputs should be exactly `2015-09-23T14:30:00`?

Comment: @codroipo yeah that's right

Comment: @BenSharpe .NET `DateTime` doesn't keep info about `TimeZone`, so, as @Rob said you need `DateTimeOffset`, to do so you have to edit your deserialization class (you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188933/prevent-timezone-conversion-on-deserialization-of-datetime-value). Anyway, I don't understand the purpose of writing a wrong date...

Comment: @codroipo Thanks, I'll have a look at that. The date is not wrong it is coming from two sources, one with UTC format and the other in BST, but both are the same time.

Comment: @BenSharpe if you want the two of them to be UTC you can call `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: @codroipo - `ToUniversalTime` on a `DateTime` converts from the server's local time to UTC.  The local time zone in Azure is already UTC, so this will effectively be a no-op.

Comment: The bigger problem is that `DateTimeOffset` doesn't play nice with `XmlSerializer`.  It serializes as a complex object, and won't deserialize standard ISO.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things working against you:

1. Your input is varied.

   - `"2015-09-23T14:30:00+01:00"` is explicitly a particular instant in time, described by a date, time, and offset from UTC.
   - `"2015-09-23T14:30:00"` does not provide an offset, so it does not *directly* map to a specific point in time.
2. When `"2015-09-23T14:30:00+01:00"` is deserialized to a `DateTime` by `XmlSerializer`, the offset is applied to get to UTC, and then it is converted to the *local time zone* of the server where it is running.  The result has `DateTimeKind.Local`.

   - In the cloud, the local time zone is already UTC, so it subtracts an hour and stays there, though it still has `DateTimeKind.Local`, not `DateTimeKind.Utc`.
   - Also note you stated `15:30`, but `14:30+01:00` is `13:30` UTC.  Also, I don't see any difference in behavior when only one or the other is in a single file.  If you can, please edit your question to show code that reproduces it in this way.
3. When `"2015-09-23T14:30:00"` is deserialized to a `DateTime` by `XmlSerializer`, it will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  If you intend to use that to mean UTC, that is an assumption you are applying after the fact.  It could just as well be the local time of some other time zone.  To explicitly be UTC, the original string should have been either `"2015-09-23T14:30:00Z"` or `"2015-09-23T14:30:00+00:00"`.
4. When `"2015-09-23T14:30:00+01:00"` is deserialized to a `DateTimeOffset` by `XmlSerializer`, it chokes.  The `XmlSerializer` class still doesn't understand the standard ISO format of a `DateTimeOffset`.  There's [some workarounds here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377036/how-can-i-xml-serialize-a-datetimeoffset-property), but really this should be fixed in the framework (IMHO).

So what to do?  Well, the easiest thing to do (and what most people end up doing) is to remove the `DateTime` properties from these classes and use `string` instead.  That way you get the exact value provided in the data.  You can then take it through `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTimeOffset.Parse` yourself, with all of the various options those methods provide.  There's an example of doing this via the "buddy properties" approach [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22190455/634824).

Once you have converted both string values to `DateTimeOffset`, you can then either use the `.DateTime` property to get the raw date and time original provided, or use `.UtcDateTime` property, or any of the other properties.

Be aware that if you parse an ISO string without an offset as a `DateTimeOffset`, one will be applied for you.  By default, it will use the *local* time zone of the computer where it's running.  If your code is in Azure, that will be UTC, or +00:00 - so it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks. In relation to the parsing the DateTimes in the same file, that is what is throwing me, when I parse a file with UTC offset it parses correctly, when I parse a file with no offset it parses correctly, then when both are in the same file the UTC offset times parse correctly but the DateTime without an offset will parse as an hour ahead. I can see no difference in the code that would cause this to happen.

Comment: Could you please update your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Thanks.    (Though the solution will likely be the same - use strings).