# Generating DateTime to XML with specific timezone

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, timezone-offset

I want to generate the following DateTime format to XML:

`2017-11-12T01:00:00-06:00`

I am in the Eastern Standard Time zone which is `-5` so when I do:

```
DateTime operatingDayLocal = DateTime.SpecifyKind(currentDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

the result is:

`2017-11-12T01:00:00-05:00`

I have to use the same DateTime format which is `T00:00:00-00:00` but keeping the same time. I only want to change the offset of the DateTime so it can be generated to XML properly.

I tried this, but the time changes and the offset is gone:

```
DateTime operatingDayCentralTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"));
```

Which results to : `2017-11-12T00:00:00`

Comment: How do you actually generate the XML ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093213/7556646

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime`, given that that's the information you want in the XML.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "generated to XML"?  You're not showing anything in your question that is about XML.  Could you please edit your question to include that code?

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: Check out [Choosing between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime).  And then see [How can I XML Serialize a DateTimeOffset Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3377036).

Comment: Simple :             string operatingDayCentralTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss-05:00");

Comment: I ended up changing the data type to a string instead of a DateTime. Then using the following code: `currentDate.ToString("o").Replace(".0000000-05:00", "-06:00");`